# Request URL cannot be made to Aura framework internal API endpoints

Tags: javascript, aura

Does anyone face with this error? How to fix it?
Aura framework says that the following code is the reason of the error:

```
window.history.replaceState({}, null, finalUrl);
```

Comment: We have encountered this too.  It seems to be occurring in Summer '20 preview instances.  We have an open ticket with Salesforce Support to determine next steps.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered a similar issue, and found this Known Issue: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Sp0EQAS

Based on the issue details, it looks like Salesforce has no plans to fix it?